# what folder DLL will be saved

Tags: vb.net

I'm a newbie to VB.net so please be easy
I'm writing a class library project and when I build solution, where the DLL is created and saved? I tried one and it's saved in bin/debug folder - Is this a default folder or I can option in diff. folder?
Thank you

Comment: My first question is why? As a noob, I'm not sure you understand this the output location of a DLL is not all that important. If this is part of another project, within the same solution, you should use project references. If there are many projects that use this, then you should make it install to the GAC after each successful test/release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `bin\debug` is the default for debug builds and `bin\release` is the default for release builds.

You can change this in the project properties on the Compile Tab.  This value can vary for the different project configurations in your project.

[image: Image of the project properties screen]